# Check array for enabled buttons and create names for each that is "true"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure if title suits my needs proparly, but I hope it will be close to what I actually need.

So I am making one small plugin for personal usage and I am wondering how to quickly create "X" amount of buttons, depending of how many social buttons I will need by the time.

For now it is three buttons, but I may enable or disable them optionally as in every plugin there.

So what I am wondering is how can I know, which button is enabled or disabled by the user into plugin and then create different button action and button text for each.

Here's example of what I have and I just want to create exact text for each enabled button.

```
var socialsCount = 0,
    socials = [this.options.facebookButton, this.options.twitterButton, this.options.googleButton];


for (i = 0; i < socials.length; i++) {
    if (socials[i] === true) {
        socialsCount++;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < socialsCount; i++) {
    $("<button />", {
        type: "button",
        class: "just some classes",
        text: 'Make button names ' + i
    }).appendTo(".vsd-body");
}
```

So in this case, it will check which buttons are true and create required amount of "buttons". Let's say in this case "facebookButton and googleButton" is "true", while "twitterButton" is "false".

How can I set "text: Make button names ' + i right there to create names for each button that is enabled.

Examples:
facebookButton - "facebook"
twitterButton - "twitter"
googleButton - "google"

I hope you understand my question. I need any kind of answer!

Comment: Not the answer but `i` isn't defined anywhere which makes it global when you use it. Also the word `class` is a reserved word so put it in quotes.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield - Thank you for the answer. "i" is just for loop to add a number :)
Thanks for mentioning, I will put it within quotes.

Comment: For `i` that's the point it's just for the loop so it shouldn't be a global variable. You need to define it locally for that it's use there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of objects

```
var options = {
   buttons:[
      { enabled:true, label:"Facebook" },
      { enabled:false, label:"Twitter" },
      { enabled:true, label:"Google" }
   ]
};

for(var i=0; i<options.buttons; i++){
   if(options.buttons[i].enabled){
      $("<button />", {
          type: "button",
          class: "just some classes",
          text: options.buttons[i].label
      }).appendTo(".vsd-body");  
   }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this will do exactly what I need. Thank you for the answer.